# Safari says "No Extensions", can't add any extensions

Tags: safari, macos-mojave

Safari extension window says "No Extension". Can't add any extension as well. I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.5 (no beta).

Following did not help : Disable/Enable Extensions from Develop menu, restarting safari, restarting mac, removing ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.SandboxBroker.plist

This might have happened after I installed a profile (.pkg file) to receive beta OS update. But I never installed the beta.

How do I add extensions to Safari ? Any help ?

[image]

Comment: Think it's Safari Version 13.0 (14608.1.29). It's under 'Preview' mode as per https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/15675/apple-safari